# jqGrid with jqueryUI conflicts with zurb foundation

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

Hi I am using jqgrid having jquery UI theme. My master page in the web site is using zurb foundation framework as our base css framework.

The web page with jqgrid renders perfect if I dont include zurb's foundation css but if I include it ...the css doesnt render properly for jqgrid.

I can see the reasons as I am trying to include two different css frameworks in one webpage and as these two frameworks have some general css classes  which are conflicting with each other.

I need to use these two frameworks as I will be using many of jqueryui components in combination with zurbfoundation components + css.

Is there a way to deal with these conflicts. One solution in my mind was to use iframes in my web page where I have jqgrid...but that would be my last last preferencce.

Or is there a way that I can use jqgrid without using jqueryUI?

Comment: it would be good if you demonstrate the conflicts which you have on a demo example and would post the URL to the demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fixed it. foundation.css had general classes for table tag and input [text] tag..commenting those classes helped to remove the conflict.

Comment: You shouldn't comment out any code from Foundations css page, try to use overrides instead. So if Foundation had a class like: `.someClass{ color: black }` and you wanted to change that, you would create an override in your `Style.css` that loads after Foundation and do something like `.someClass{ color: white }` or whatever. But if you change too much of the Foundation.css you won't be able to upgrade to a new version without going into the new version and making all the same changes you made to the original. Just saying, you should always use overrides for these types of frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet to override the default Foundation table styles:

```
.ui-widget table {
    border: none;
}

.ui-widget table tbody tr:nth-child(even),
.ui-widget table thead, 
.ui-widget table tfoot {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```